# Mac NSView animation animationDidEnd called twice on Retina MBP

Tags: macos, retina-display, nsanimation

A bug recently showed up in my app related to view animation on the new MBP Retina.  I don't have a new MPB to reproduce but the affected user is helping track down the issue through copious amounts of debugging output.  It appears that animationDidEnd is being called twice on my animation delegate, the second time seems to be screwing things up immensely.  The code has worked on 10.5-10.7.4 for quite some time now and this seems to be isolated to the new MBP Retina so far.

I am using the view itself as the animation delegate in case something about the relationship between the view and the animation delegate has changed which precludes this possibility.  I'm also further investigating the possibility of the animationDidEnd method being called by two distinct animation objects (though I have nothing to indicate that another animation is running anywhere in the app, let alone for this delegate).

If anyone is aware of any updates to documentation related to animation delegates I would appreciate a pointer, or any ideas otherwise.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: The issue didn't have to do with animations at all.  It had to do with use of the deprecated method convertPointFromBase:

While deprecated methods are "usually" ok for at least the next release, this one is trouble when it comes to the Retina display.  This is only conjecture, but since the method works as expected on non-Retina displays, I have to assume this has to do with the pixel density on the new displays.